# External site copying (curl) site, how to redirect

Tags: php, curl, centos, ip, varnish

I got the following problem.

My website is being copied 1:1 to another domain and by another server and the only thing changed is the advertisement.

Domain A got a .com domain and is the original site ( and owned by me)

Domain B got a .ee domain and is copying 1:1 the original site ( owned by shady Estonian company )

They probably use curl to get the the content and change the advertisement to their own.
Legal steps are under way , but will take a very long time ( as we all know).

In the meantime I would like this current ip ( from the server ripping my content) to show a different page.

**Problem :**

My server is using Varnish cashing , so php/apache based redirection means my own users will see the wrong page ( if cashed).
Should I use javascript to determine ip and then redirect ? ( slowing down load time for all users)

**Q:**

How do I serve a different page based on IP while varnish cache is running.

Server :

Centos 6.4

Apache,
Varnish

PHP 5+

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check the domain - if it's not your domain, redirect. You can make the script load asynchronously, so it doesn't block the loading of other scripts.

You can block curl/perl user agents, but changing the user agent is 1 minute of work, so don't expect too much from it. :)

You can also configure fail2ban to scan for IPs with too many requests per second and add them in the iptables for good.

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: One of the easiest ways to stop `cURL` is to use a `<noframe>` redirect to a disabled page. `cURL` can't support javascript and therefore the page won't load for them. This will affect who can use your site by some extremely marginal amount. Those using `noscript` extensions in their browsers should actually land on a page, and simply explain to them the reasoning that it's been disabled.

Comment: That's the reason I use .NET to write IE based bots for crawling web pages. Slower, of course, but harder to block ;)

Comment: Right, totally understand that as well. However, you're in a small percentile of people who would actually go out of their way to do this. Most people using `cURL` are script kiddies with copy+pasta.

Comment: What if I would not mind being crawled by other sites , since they only use content that is allowed.  Ip based blocking>redirecting is what I am looking for.  Completely block the ip is my last option.  I want to use their incoming users and redirect them to the legal site ( best option).

Comment: You cannot use javascript to get the server's IP. It can only tell you the hostnme of the website.